# Items don't exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wondering why, in my code-behind, sometimes I have to use special tricks in order for it to see elements in my .aspx webform and other times I do not.
For example:

```
DropDownList clrslct = (DropDownList)FindControl("ColorSelector");
clrslct.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"].Value;
```

Sometimes I have to write that in order for my code-behind to see tags in its associated .aspx file. other times i can simply call the tag's ID in my code and it works fine. does anyone have any idea why this is?

Full Code (from http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/ ) is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Cookies</title>
</head>
<body runat="server" id="BodyTag">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ColorSelector" autopostback="true" onselectedindexchanged="ColorSelector_IndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem value="White" selected="True">Select color...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="Red">Red</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="Green">Green</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="Blue">Blue</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;`enter code here`
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace cookiesSessionsViewStates
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"] != null)
            {
                DropDownList clrslct = (DropDownList)FindControl("ColorSelector");
                clrslct.SelectedValue = Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"].Value;
                BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = clrslct.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

        protected void ColorSelector_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BodyTag.Style["background-color"] = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("BackgroundColor");
            cookie.Value = ColorSelector.SelectedValue;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that during postbacks, on when the page is pre-rendered, you have not yet bound the drop down list - and when you are trying to find the value in the list - it is just not there yet? i.e. I think the "special tricks" you are referring to, is accessing the drop down during different states of the page cycle.

Comment: I think your problem is about variable and control scope. [other times i can simply call the tag's ID in my code and it works fine]: that's because the associated control is in the current scope

Comment: Well, I don't see why, since this all happens with intellisense during  design phase. I've been having to do this ever since i've started using ASP.NET, but I've recently been prompted to ask here after trying to take a tutorial @ http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/ and wondering why the tutor doesn't have to do what I do to get his/her projects to work. I've added the  full code to the original post.

Comment: @AliRashidi that's what seems to be the problem, I guess that I just don't see how i'm supposed to tell whether I'm in scope or not between an .aspx page and a .cs one.

Comment: Why do you use FindControl method to find colorSelector DropDownList?

Comment: Don't you have a aspx.designer.cs file somewhere, or do you create your controls in code? If there is no member of the page with the name ColorSelector, you can't reference it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AliRashidi because the control seems to be out of scope, and I'm not sure if it's supposed to be that way or not.

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I do, but the comments in that file says it's auto-generated and rarely do I touch those files. How do i get my controls listed in there? I've tried a rebuild but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: simply aspx web forms miss a file named Designer.cs which includes information about all the controls on the current page. that's why you'll need to use FindControl Method. but so far I have not yet totally understood your problem

Comment: @AliRashidi FindControl seems to work, (even though it feels like a cheap and improper hack) but I cannot use it for the BodyTag ID.

Comment: I just tested out something because I never really verified this, but if you use the designer view and drop controls on it, you get entries in a designer file for that member.  I took a dropdowlist from the toolbox and dropped it in a DIV.  I got a nice entry in the designer file. Same thing with a Label, ok. Typing the same control in the aspx file --> nothing!

Comment: There we go. Note to self, use the toolbox!! Thanks @Schwarzie2478 I hope this is fixed in 2013

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FindControl from within things like grid view row events or repeating controls item created event -- because there isn't one control, there are zero or more controls, with similar names/id's.

Those controls are in [NamingContainer's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and that is the basis for finding them within their templates. If you are creating a web application, a designer.cs file will be created and visible to you (it gets created for web sites too, but only at compile time), and anything in it can be accessed from within your codebehind class.

So, simple answer: in a naming container, you will have to use FindControl or similar to find it, outside of naming container it can be addressed directly.

Comment: It looks like you're saying that I can access them directly if my C# code is wrapped around <%# %> tags within the .aspx file. but what if i wanted the code to be in the code-behind? It's my understanding that this will make the code server-side(what i want) and not client-side.

Comment: @Laserbeak43: No, all of your code (except any javascript) is server side only.  The difference is that some of the controls don't exist at design time due to being inside structures that get created ON THE SERVER at runtime.  Those can't be referenced in the same way as controls that exist at design time -- the compiler/intellisense dosn't know about them becuase they don't yet exist.

Comment: @Laserbeak43: basically you should be seeing the ColorSelector control. Either you have a problem with your code or there's a bug in Visual Studio -- I have seen there be a delay in VS recognizing new controls, generally. I just ignore it, but on occassion I have quit and reopened the solution.

Comment: it looks like Schwarzie2478 found the issue, the designer.cs doesn't detect when elements are written onto the form(at least not immediately). but they are created when they're dragged from the toolbox. Thanks for clearing up the difference between server and client-side code too.

Comment: @Laserbeak43: in my experience, it is recognize (when typed in by hand) almost immediately, most of the time.  When it doesn't, telling it build first generally fixes the problem.  I think there is some bug in there somewhere, because I have definitely seen it fail to recognize a new control (even though it might recognize a control entered afterwards) without reopening the solution.  Never tried to use the designer to add the control to see if that would get it to recognize that things have changed. Never had reopening the solution fail to resolve it either, but that's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'll have to stick to FindControl for now, if i want the code to stay in my code-behind.
I ended up using:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl bdyBodyTag = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl)FindControl("BodyTag");
```

Thanks for all of the suggestions.